# What is the use of a little bag of sand?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment

In the Scholar's pack on page 151 of the PHB it notes that you get a 'little bag of sand'. Is there any mention of what the intended use of that is in-game? I haven't found anything in the equipment chapter.

Given the volume of off-topic answers I'll summarize the question as so: Why is it given to Scholars specifically; what use is the bag of sand to a scribe or other scholarly person?

Comment: If you just want to make up uses for sand but are not sure why it was included in the 5e equipment list, do not answer this question.  This is not a brainstorming site.

Comment: It seems like this is explicitly asking for the "intended use", which would make it a designer-reasons question and thus [no longer allowed on the site](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/33569) (though they were allowed at the time it was asked). This seems to be reflected by the fact that most of the answers seem to be speculating or generating ideas about ways it *could* be used, without providing any support the idea that those were the intended use of the item (a common issue with designer-reasons questions). As such, it seems like this question should probably be closed.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Sand is one thing used by scribes to blot ink, so that a document can be handled or moved soon after working on it, without dripping or smearing. You can assume it sees use as a matter of course while the character is mapping a dungeon or composing a letter.

Apart from that intended use in a scholar's pack, it can probably be put to many creative uses under dire circumstances that have nothing to do with ancient ink's inconveniently-long drying time.

Comment: Sand is also used in the quill-preparing process.

Comment: Comments are not for random discussion. Submit your own answer if you have other thoughts.

Comment: http://www.fountainpennetwork.com/forum/topic/156685-sand-used-instead-of-blotting-paper/

Answer (score 14):

The [classic, cinematic use of a bag of sand](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pr-8AP0To4k) by a scholar comes from the opening scene of *Raiders of the Lost Ark* in which it is used in an attempt to disable a weight-sensitive trap. Shame Harrison fluffed his roll.

That said, D&D 5 harkens back to the era of having *players* find creative solutions to problems (as opposed to rolling dice to let the characters find them which become more common from 3.x), so it probably doesn't have any *specific* intended use. It is there to spark creativity.

Use it to mark a trail, hit a goblin (if you can't find a half brick), draw mystic symbols, make a Mind Flayer's undergarments uncomfortable to wear, reveal an invisible bridge (Indy really did like his sand), or whatever else you can come up with.

Comment: So why don't **all** adventurers start with a bag of sand? What's so special about scholars?

Comment: Because it is thematic (adventuring scholars are like Indiana Jones and thus carry a bag of sand) not practical.

Answer (score 1):

Arguably, it could work as a material component for the spell "Sleep" since one of the options are "A pinch of fine sand."

Answer (score -2):

I think that the intended purpose is to use your imagination. The bag of sand is just like the various trinkets you get, they don't have something built into the system for their use.

Here are a few possibilities for a bag of sand:

You can use it to exfoliate before going to a ball where you intend to assassinate a corrupt local merchant.

You can use it to remove the rust from a corroded metal plaque to read the symbols underneath.

Use it to test the direction of the wind.

Sprinkle it on the floor so that an invisible creature leaves footprints.

For a charismatic character with the charlatan background, sell it as fairy dust.

Comment: very strange, why the downvotes?

Comment: The question is asking for the intended use of the sand and you just listed a bunch of random stuff to use it for.

Comment: I see your point, I'll modify it slightly

Comment: If the purpose of this answer is to point out that it's a great item for improvisation, what does this answer add that is not already in Quentin's answer?

Comment: @GMJoe It adds specificity. Which is useful for firing the imagination. The answer would have been improved by including the historical ink blotting uses of sand, but most everything can be improved.